# Adding DLLs to VS2008 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

How do I add Prolog DLLs to VS2008 in order to embed Prolog within C++?

Are these three dlls sufficient:

```
libpl.lib
plterm.lib
pthreadVC.lib
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the project properties page (can be accessed from the Project pull down menu), going to the references tab, and adding the path to the .dll files you want to use.

After you hit the add reference button, you may want to use the Browse tab and find the .dll files on your machine.